# com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton is deprecated

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend

I noticed PlusOneButton was not working for some time now. I had it to link to the Google Play store URL (i.e. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.package.app).

Now that when I upgrade the library version to "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:12.0.0" or higher, it indicates PlusOneButton is deprecated.

Is there another way to use PlusOneButton? Or is Google removing the PlusOneButton feature entirely?

Comment: Maybe there is something you need to know further from their [release last march 28, 2018](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_28_2018_-_version_1201). Also kindly check the [button policy](https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy) if you missed something.

Comment: Thank you @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I checked both links you provided, nothing much mentioned about the deprecation of PlusOneButton.

Comment: Any idea about this? If they deprecate, they should show what to use instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching for PlusOneButton in Google led to [PlusOneButton](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusOneButton) site, which lead to 
[Plus API Deprecation Notes](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/api-deprecation).

I guess you just have to send your content to Google+ app through Intent or use [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) in your app and explore it's possibilities or use other solutions suggested on [People API site](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People).

Btw. here's the library to implement custom Google Sign in button: https://github.com/shobhitpuri/custom-google-signin-button according to newest guidelines.

Comment: Why deprecate the button though? It was a nice way to do +1 to the app, without going through multiple phases. It could also show how many did it. What should people use instead? Or just remove it?